# How can I get my discord.js bot to read/write in other channels?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here's the code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
    // send back "Pong." to the channel the message was sent in
    message.channel.send('Pong.');
}
});

client.login('');
```

It works fine in the main channel, however, when I call it from a separate channel, this error happens:

```
(node:8620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\epopova1\Desktop\poserBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:8620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8620) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because your bot doesn't have to proper permissions from the server to carry out the functions you want it to.

Kick your bot from the server. Then you'd put your bot invite link in your browser.
It'd look something like this:

`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=708381241052546648`

Let's say this above, is your link to invite your bot.

Cut off everything off your link until/unless it looks like this:

`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=708351240052146248`

Then just append this onto the end of your link:

`&permissions=68608&scope=bot`

So then as an example your link would look like:

`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=7083819999999648&permissions=68608&scope=bot`

This will give the bot everything it needs in order to do the above code.

Comment: edit: it was a discord channel perms error. Thanks for the help!